# Is there any reporting tool or a gem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am looking for a reporting gem or tool in ruby on rails. its for a e-commerce app, where I need to generate lot of data like sales report, marketing reporting,etc, I want to keep it more generic and open so that the users can get any kind of report.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look the question I asked another day: [is there any Ruby or Rails reporting tools based on customizable templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843325/is-there-any-ruby-or-rails-reporting-tools-based-on-customizable-templates)

Thin Reports and ODF report are very good. If you need to compare more reporting gems try [The Ruby Box: reporting section](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting.html). There are few other good reporting tools as well.

here is my summary about thin reports and ODF report:

[Thin Reports](http://www.thinreports.org/): It is really good. You download a template editor then you define your own report template then by combine the thinreports gems you can get SVG or PDF report out of your application.

[ODF Report](https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report): It uses ODF file as template which can be edit by OpenOffice and MS Word 2010. Then You get your report out.

Comment: By the way, the English version of the GUI Designer has been released on July 2, 2012. I hope this will help. 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/thinreports/

Answer (score 1):

For graphical reports, check out the answers to this question:

[Ruby on Rails: What Reporting and/or Charting Tools Are Available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051877/ruby-on-rails-what-reporting-and-or-charting-tools-are-available)

For raw stats, I've been using the [statistics](https://github.com/acatighera/statistics) gem - I'm not sure if it's still maintained.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the new gem [active reporting](https://github.com/t27duck/active_reporting)
and here is [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MczzCfTQGfU) about in rails conf 2017

Answer (score 0):

Some of the more popular reporting tools for Ruby are listed [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting).